# How to avoid signed zero in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two double variable say A and B.
Column A will always have positive value and column B can have both postive and negative value both.

When I am trying to divide the above two variables:
A/B

B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
0.0/-5.4

### Result

(-0.0)

I am expecting a value 0.0 but instead I am getting -0.0.
Can you suggest me ways to mitigate this issue in PIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to go for bicond operator (?:).

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (a:double,b:double);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (a == 0 ? a : ((b == 0) ? NULL :  a/b)) AS c;
DUMP B;
```

**Input : a.csv**

```
 0.0,-5.0
 -4.0,-2.0
 -4.0,2.0
 5.0,0
```

**Output : DUMP B**

```
 (0.0)
 (2.0)
 (-2.0)
 ()
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it worked for this scenario. but for scenario consider 6.0/-6.0 , I am getting -1.0 which is the expected result.So I can't use ABS method here. Any leads on this?

Comment: @user131990 : Updated answer, please check.

Comment: What about 0.0,-5.0 scenario.I think it will give -0.0. I am mainly facing this issue for the scenario when A is 0 and B is some negative number.So i am getting -0.0 value,so for this scenario I used ABS method but when I use this ABS method other scenarios such as -4.0/2.0 or 4.0/-4.0 will not give wrong results.

Comment: @user131990 : We are checking if first operand i.e. a is 0 if yes, then we are having it as value of a i.e 0.0. In the use case which you are interested in it will still give 0.0.

Comment: @user131990 : great you can accept the answer if this answers your question